# Add jQuery Mobile UI Elements via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery Mobile. Currently I am dynamically adding a custom header using javascript to the html file. I would like to add a jQuery mobile header using javascript, by appending it to the DOM. Adding this to the .html code directly is no option.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

-> Load the js file that has the document ready function for creating the DOM elements before the jquery mobile js.
-> Simply change this in the header of the .html file.

Answer (score 1):

not sure I understand the question. do you mean something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener('yourevent',function(){
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'path/to/your/jquery script src';
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
},false);

</script>
```

Comment: oops had a type in getElementsByTagName - fixed!

Comment: thanks for the idea. I am trying to add a jquery mobile object to the DOM. jQuery mobile adds special css rules/formating to objects when the website is loaded. Adding all the properties is tedious. For instance the list has the function listview() of doing so.

Comment: could you refine what exactly do you mean in "jquery mobile object"